# Read lines from file and split them in Python

Tags: python, matrix, split

I have a task to read data from file.
This is the first file:

```
10001-31021 Nagy Árpád 2015.12.30. 524432
10001-31121 Zagyva László Pál 2016.03.21. 765432
10012-34321 Acél Tibor 2016.02.20. 231231
10201-11021 Lakatos Pál 2016.01.10. 2310456
10210-41011 Nagy Árpád 2016.02.03. 323532
```

I have to work with these infos. My question is how to split them and put them into a two dimensional matrix. The main problem is some names has 3 word some has 2. I was / am searching for solution on the internet but i couldn't find anything.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you expect it to be split? Like this: ["10001-31021", "Nagy Árpád", "2015.12.30.", "524432"]?

Comment: Please show your own attempt at this and explain what explicit difficulties with respect to your own code you are having. Readers wanting to answer your question will be more inclined and able to answer your question. You want to put together a better [MCVE] of your problem.

Comment: you might have to use regex in order to achieve the following parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using regular expression, you can try building it with indices (if they are going to be at the same position in every line).

```
a = """10001-31021 Nagy Árpád 2015.12.30. 524432
10001-31121 Zagyva László Pál 2016.03.21. 765432
10012-34321 Acél Tibor 2016.02.20. 231231
10201-11021 Lakatos Pál 2016.01.10. 2310456
10210-41011 Nagy Árpád 2016.02.03. 323532"""

def add_it(lines):
  matrix =[]
  for i in lines:
    row = []
    b = i.split(" ")
    row.append(b.pop(0))
    row.append(b.pop(-2))
    row.append(b.pop(-1))
    row.insert(1, (" ".join(b)).strip())
    matrix.append(row)
  return matrix

print(add_it(a.split("\n")))
```

You can try it [online](https://repl.it/G2tQ/4)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the pattern for rest of the data columns, you can do something like this :

```
text = "10001-31021 Nagy Árpád 2015.12.30. 524432"
text_list = test.split()
result = [text_list[0], ' '.join(text_list[1:-2]), text_list[-2], text_list[-1]]
print(result)
```

The above code will result :

```
['10001-31021', 'Nagy \xc3\x81rp\xc3\xa1d', '2015.12.30.', '524432']
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue with the file is with the name.

So first you do the split method as we do normally.

If you observe, the row[1:-2] is the name you require.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can observe that first and last two elements of each row are fixed, so:

```
line.split()[:1] # first element
line.split()[-2:] # last two elements
line.split()[1:-2] # middle elements
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answers! Really good community!

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution using a regular expression:

```py
import re

data = []
with open("x") as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.fullmatch('([^ ]+) (.*) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)', line.strip())
        data.append([match.group(1), match.group(2), match.group(3), match.group(4)])
```

`data` is going to look like this:

```py
[
    ['10001-31021', 'Nagy Árpád', '2015.12.30.', '524432'],
    ['10001-31121', 'Zagyva László Pál', '2016.03.21.', '765432'],
    ['10012-34321', 'Acél Tibor', '2016.02.20.', '231231'],
    ['10201-11021', 'Lakatos Pál', '2016.01.10.', '2310456'],
    ['10210-41011', 'Nagy Árpád', '2016.02.03.', '323532']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

With a regex you can try:

```
import re 
subject = """10001-31021 Nagy Árpád 2015.12.30. 524432
10001-31121 Zagyva László Pál 2016.03.21. 765432
10012-34321 Acél Tibor 2016.02.20. 231231
10201-11021 Lakatos Pál 2016.01.10. 2310456
10210-41011 Nagy Árpád 2016.02.03. 323532"""

lines = subject.split("\n")
results_list = []
for line in lines:
    p = re.search(r"^([\d-]+)\s+([A-zÀ-ÿ\s]+)\s+([\d.]+)\s+([\d]+)", line)
    if p:
        results_list.append([p.group(1), p.group(2), p.group(3), p.group(4)])
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/q381zf)